# Cannot install R-base in Ubuntu 18.04 - Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: 18.04, r

I am trying to install `r-base` using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rrutter3.5

sudo apt-get install -y r-base

sudo apt-get install -y gdebi-core
```

However, this happens:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
 r-base : Depends: r-recommended (= 3.5.1-1bionic) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: try to install `r-recommended` has it is said in the error message, do it with `sudo apt install r-recommended` command line (or  `sudo apt install r-recommended r-base` if you don't want to retype the command line to install `r-base`)

Comment: Have you run apt-get update between the first two commands?

Comment: If you didn't run `sudo apt-get update` before you attempted to install the package, you don't have updated package source information.  You need to run `sudo apt-get update` first to help resolve those issues.

Comment: I have tried sudo apt-get update, sudo apt install r-recommended r-base, and the script in the attached question. However, it still does not fix my problem. The error is shown below 
r-recommended : Depends: r-cran-kernsmooth (>= 2.2.14) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: r-cran-mgcv (>= 1.1.5) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: r-cran-mass but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: r-cran-class but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: r-cran-nnet but it is not going to be installed